# Rearrange/Push or Pull Bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a strange situation wherein I've 2 Bootstrap tabs. Let's call them A & B. 
Case I: If tab A is marked as default tab then it should show like:

**A** | B

with A also being the active tab at the same time!

Case II: If tab B is marked as default tab then it should show like:

**B** | A

with B also being the active tab at the same time!

I've configured the application in such a way, that the user can select the default tab now & it is shown as active. 
But, how to show the default tab as the 1st one? Is there anything like push or pull we've in Bootstrap can be used here?

Here's the bootstrap code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabA">Tab A</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabB">Tab B</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tabA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
              <h3>Tab A</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="tabB" class="tab-pane fade">
              <h3>Tab B</h3>
              <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, if tab B is marked as default, it will remove the class active from A and add it to B. Also, a   is created. This part is working fine.

However, how do I ensure, when tab B is marked as default, it is also shown as the 1st tab?

Comment: you should also post a working demo of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.

Just added a class 'default' when a tab is marked as default.

And then,

```
ul.nav-tabs {
    display: flex;
}

li.default {
    order: -1; /* the default is 0 */
}
```